# Convert String with Umlaut in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a textfield input that returns a string like this:

```
let name = "B\U00f6se"
```

how can I convert the umlaut so \U00f6 (and any other special character) gets replaced with it's proper equivalent:

```
name = "Böse";
```

Thanks for your help!

//Seb

Comment: So the user types the characters "B", "\", "U", "0", ... into the text field? Then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759574/best-way-to-convert-back-and-forth-from-unichars-to-display-characters-objectiv (and translating that form Objective-C to Swift should not be too difficult :)

Comment: _Why_ does your input return that? It is possible to type ö directly in iOS.

Comment: @matt maybe that's the question. I'm using a form based on this library: [SwiftForms](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms). And it returns all the input in a dictionary. Whenever there is a special character it returns something like the above. Any ideas?

Comment: @Seb: The `description` method of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` use the `\Unnnn` syntax to print any non-ASCII character. But as soon as you assign a dictionary value to a string, you should see what you expect. – See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340103/1187415 for an example

Comment: @MartinR I see. OK so the Dictionary prints to the logs like this: `{
    gender = M; 
    name = "\U00d6ser"
}` How do I assign name to a string correctly?

Comment: If the user enters an ö you've _got_ the ö. There is no there there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `description` method of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` use `\Unnnn`
escape sequences for all non-ASCII characters.

In the Xcode sample project that comes with SwiftForms, the submit method 
displays this description to the user:

```
func submit(_: UIBarButtonItem!) {

    let message = self.form.formValues().description
    let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Form output", message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

and the effect is that you see for example

```
lastName = "B\U00f6se";
```

But the `description` method is only suited for debugging or logging.
What you should do instead is to enumerate all keys and values:

```
for (key, value) in self.form.formValues() {
    println("\(key) = \(value)")
}
```

which would show you

```
lastName = Böse
```

or retrieve the form values that you are interested in:

```
if let lastName = self.form.formValues()["lastName"] as? String {
    println(lastName) // Böse
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comments I just figured out something very similar! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way.

```
let name = "B\u{00f6}se"
pinrtln(name)
```

For more detail look at [this entry](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/)